# Sleep multiple thread groups at the same time

Tags: jmeter

I am wondering if multiple thread groups can be made non-active/sleeping at the same time.

I need multiple thread groups that run infinitely, with alternating intervals times of being all active and being all asleep/non-active. This is to simulate ongoing periods of high and low/no activity. It seems there are only controllers and 'think time' objects inside thread groups but not across thread groups.

My test plan is rather simple in structure.

- Test plan (parallel execution of all thread groups)

  - thread group 1 - infinite
  - thread group 2 - infinite

Comment: Welcome to the community. 
I would suggest keep adding the solutions you have tried and observations/failures. So one can easily help you for specific failure. Happy Testing @Grillian!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider adding i.e. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput) which obeys [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) and has access to the number of active threads in all Thread Groups

[image]

You can set the "Target throughput" to read the value of a JMeter Property using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and when you want to "sleep" - set the property value to `0` using either [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) or the [Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)